# Uniform convergence of sequence of functions on every compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

I have a sequence $(x_n)$ of continuous functions: $$x_n\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

If it is convergent on $[-a,a]$, $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$, with limit $x$, what do I further need to determine if $x_n\to x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (According to the sup-norm)? E.g. differentiability?

Is there an applicable statement that is generalizable to Banach-spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "convergent"? Pointwise convergent?

Comment: Also you are using $x_n$ and $x$ in way different ways. It's confusing.

Comment: $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ seems to be a sequence of real functions that converges pointwise on $[-a,a]$ to the function $x$.

Comment: No, $(x_n)$ is a sequence of functions which, restricted to $[-a,a]$, I then consider as points in the space $\mathcal{C}([-a,a],\mathbb{R})$ that I equip with the sup-norm (as is default), that is, I mean uniform convergence. I should have said the functions were continuous, though... Assuming convergence, the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ I call $x$. So, $x$ is just a name for the limit of $x_n$ and is a function, too.

Comment: I see, well as the answers show that is a rather hopeless endeavor. Notice how even Andrew D. Hwang's example converges uniformly to its limit (which happens to be the identity function) on $[-a,a]$ for every fixed real number $a>0$ but the sequence does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ denote the identity function, $I(x) = x$. There's no reason to expect that *any* local condition (such as continuity, differentiability, or real-analyticity) guarantees that if $(f_{n}) \to I$ uniformly on $[-a, a]$ for all $a > 0$, then $(f_{n}) \to I$ uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$.

The sequence $(f_{n})$ defined by
$$
f_{n}(x) = x + \tfrac{1}{n} x^{2}
$$
confirms the suspicion.

Comment: Even simpler is the sequence $f_n(x) = x/n$ converging to $0$ on every compact subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AOrtiz: OP asked for a sequence converging to the identity. (Granted, $f_{n}(x) = (1 + \frac{1}{n})x$ also works.)

Comment: Thanks, I got it. @AOrtiz comment did help to, $x$ was just the name of the limit, I did not intend do denote the identity...

Comment: @AOrtiz. I was going to propose $f_n(x)=x-1+e^{-x}\sum_{j=0}^nx^j/j!$  because I was thinking of power series of entire functions. But $f_n(x)=x(1+1/n)$ is about as simple as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

each real $c $ can be put in an interval of the form $[-b,b] $.

thus a pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions $(f_n) $ at $[-b,b] $ implies  that $(f_n (c))$ converges.

hence, there will be a pointwise convergence at $\Bbb R $.

Comment: Yes of course, but its about all the reals at once, isn't it? I did not feel confident enough to go from compact sets to the reals... I am pretty new to the sup-norm...